# How to save current web tab URLs using a batch file (no bookmarks, extensions, etc.)

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry, batch-file, url

I have read plenty of solutions pointing to bookmarks, or extensions that copy to the clipboard, etc... I am not interested in these solutions; they are exactly what I am trying to automate around by having a batch execution save current tab URLs automatically.

**Basically, where can I read the current address of open Chrome tabs in order to save them to a text file?**

This data has to be *somewhere!*

I asked this on a different site and was pointed to the registry... My study has yielded no results on where the data would actually be inside the registry for active Chrome tab URLs.

If there is something accessible holding the current Chrome tab URLs, then all I need to do is direct my batch to this data and write it to a text file.

Comment: Current Tabs holds this under your Chrome profile directory (likely Default), but this data isn't written till Chrome is closed. Plus the file contains a lot of non-text data Chrome apparently uses and is otherwise pretty mangled, so readability probably depends on whether you can extract the necessary data.